# The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I want to upload images using php to the S3 bucket.

But I keep getting this error

```
 The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
```

I have tried to find a solution for this issue. but all solutions suggest using  "AWS SDK".

I m aware that I have to set the signature to Version 4 and change the endpoint since my bucket is in Frankfurt.

But I don't know how to customize the class I'm using for uploading.

> https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483795/cant-access-s3-pre-signed-url-due-to-authorization/34495454#34495454):

> Using some help I've found the answer, which was a combination of 2
>   missing pieces (one of which was referred to in the comments):
>
> 1) Need to set this:
>
> ```
> System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY,
> ```
>
> "true");
>
> 2) Must set the "endPoint" (which was not required for upload or
>   download):
>
> ```
> s3Client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
> ```
>
> Optionally it might be useful to also add this:
>
> ```
> s3Client.setS3ClientOptions(new S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
> ```